# Spring automating generic bean creation via external factory

Tags: java, spring

I have a generic interface and some classes that implement it, e.g.:

```
interface Product { ... }
class Beverage implements Product { ... }
class Food implements Product { ... }
...

interface Worker<T extends Product> { ... }
class BeverageWorker implements Worker<Beverage> { ... }
class FoodWorker implements Worker<Food> { ... }
...
```

I have a Spring config defining beans for the above:

```
class SpringConfig {
  @Bean BeverageWorker beverageWorker() { return new BeverageWorker(...); }
  @Bean FoodWorker foodWorker() { return new FoodWorker(...); }
  ...
}
```

Assuming I have a generic way of creating these, i.e.:

```
BeverageWorker beverageWorker = WorkerFactory.workerFor(Beverage.class);
FoodWorker foodWorker = WorkerFactory.workerFor(Food.class);
...
```

is there a way to write the above `SpringConfig` to be generic somehow in order to avoid enumerating all types manually?

I.e. something like:

```
class SpringConfig {
  @Bean
  <T extends Product> Worker<T> genericWorker(Class<T> productClass) {
    return WorkerFactory.workerFor(productClass);
  }
}
```

but also ask Spring to call this method whenever it requires bean of type `Worker<T extends Product>`.

Comment: Can't you have your `WorkerFactory` object receive a `Product` as a parameter for `workerFor` method?

Comment: I don't know if this is feasible You can write an annotation, @Worker, annotate the Worker classes and somehow instantiate them at run time using Reflection API